# UDP Comunication help using C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sockets, udp

I am a Mechanical Engineer graduate student. My expertise is on optimal control and modeling, not on network protocol communication, which happens to be needed to run some experiments for my thesis. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have an OpenHaptics application that quickly reads the 6-element vector of doubles from a Geomagic Touch (Formerly Sensable Phantom). I need to send this using UDP to a target system (Speedgoat Target Machine) where I have implemented the motion and control argorithms.

I know the IP Address and Port of both machines, as I had this running using matlab (works like swimming in thick syrup).

How can I add a UDP functionality (send/receive) to my script? Replicating the process that works on Matlab logically reads like this:

```
[Windows] 
7-doubles to 56-uint8 to udp-send(IP1:soket1)
[Speedgoat]
udp-receive(IP2:soket2) 56-uint8 to 7 doubles
```

Then the reverse is possible...

```
[Speedgoat]
7-doubles to 56-uint8 to udp-send(IP2:soket3)
[windows]
udp-receive(IP1:soket4) 56-uint8 to 7 doubles
```

There are things like ensuring ports exist and are open (taken care of), and understanding the configuration of the port (byte alignment, little/big endian) that I know that they should be, so if I need to set them I can answer those questions.

Comment: in the Matlab language? or in C++?

Comment: Handy reading: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/ Sections 5.8 and 6.3 should be the most relevant.

Comment: In C++, I moved away from Matlab environment due to the slowness of it.

Comment: Thank you! I have read the document and got some stuff goi g right now